# Assigning a value to an sql search query

Tags: php, sql

I am building a point system for social networking site. I would like a number of points assigned for different degrees that a user holds. I have figured out how to access the database and determine if the user actually has the degree or not, but I am unsure of how to actually write a code that gives a point value to the results of the search. This is what I have so far, please advise:

```
$assoc = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE uid = '" . Foundry::user()->id . "' AND (data = 'ASSOCIATES' OR data = 'ASSOCIATES1' OR data = 'ASSOCIATES2'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($assoc))
{
**return //value = 0.5;** <---This is the part where I am not sure how to give a value to the search results. I would like them to earn a half of a point for holding this degree type.
}

$bach = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE uid = '" . Foundry::user()->id . "' AND (data = 'BACHELORS' OR data = 'BACHELORS1' OR data = 'BACHELORS2'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bach))
{
**return //value = 1.0;** <---This is the part where I am not sure how to give a value to the search results. I would like them to earn one point for holding this degree type.
}
```

Comment: It was highly unclear what is your desired output, could you provide an example?

Comment: For example, during registration, my users enter information about their education. If they have an Associate's Degree and a Bachelor's Degree I would like them to earn 1/2 of a point for the Associate's and 1 point for the Bachelor's. I do not want these points displayed anywhere, I just want them stored away for later use in a search algorithm my partner is developing. I was under the impression the "return" function would assign the value but not display it anywhere as of yet.

Comment: So your query (`$bach`) returns 0 rows if user does not have, and returns rows if has? Then you check `if(mysqli_num_rows() > 0) { // query for insert points into db, because you need it for later use`

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense, thank you! Would I follow it with something like this? INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)